# Where are Azure Static Web App files located?

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I have an Azure Static Web App, which is deployed with Azure DevOps pipeline.

Is there a way to locate my static files?

I saw in the pipeline that files are deployed to **/ss-oryx/app** folder but I don't know where it's located.

Files are not either in a blob storage like it was I think few months ago...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/ss-oryx/app` path is where the files will be during the pipeline run temporarily before they get published them to SWA.

**In static webapps you cannot find the output files of the build and all the output files generated will be managed by the platform only as per the By-design**